# LED mcd conversion

Tags: led

I'm trying to control an LED through my 3.3V STM32 microcontroller. I selected [this LED](https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/AM2520SURCK09.pdf) and I'm trying to run the LED at about 500-1000mcd but the datasheet only show me the TYP and MAX value

[image]

How do I convert this graph into mcd?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You left the important part out. It reads next to the graph that it is normalized intensity at 20mA, and the intensity at 20mA is typically 3000 but 1900 at minimum.

So typically, to down to 1000 mcd, use one third of 20mA current. But there are tolerances. If the guaranteed minimum is 1900 mcd, then roughly 1000 mcd can be achieved with roughly 10mA.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Red Reference LED to calibrate your absolute levels for NIST traceable accuracy.

But for ballpark levels if you have a nominal part, rated for 3000 mcd at peak centre axis and 50% at +/- 10 deg for a 20 deg. beamwidth then to get 1000 mcd so then you choose 1/3 of the nominal 20mA = 6.67 mA and for 500 mcd you choose 1/6th of the 20 mA nominal rated current or 3.33 mA